# Blueprints cannot find `static` directory for url_prefixed pages

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

Been through every question asked here on same topic, but couldn't get my issue resolved. I have a project (modified version of [this](https://github.com/mbithenzomo/project-dream-team-three)) directory setted up this way;

[image]

I have two links to go to from home page

```
     <a href="{{ url_for('home.admin_dashboard') }}"> Admin Dashboard </a>
     <a href="{{ url_for('home.dashboard') }}"> Dashboard </a>
```

The admin dashboard page is prefixed by `/admin/dashboard` whereas the other is `/dashboard`. I am creating `home` blueprint (inside home.**init**.py) by providing the relative path of root `static` directory;

```
home = Blueprint('home', __name__, static_url_path='/app/static', static_folder="static")
```

both the home page and the dashboard page can find the static directory (and load properly), but the `admin/dashboard` CANNOT fetch `static/` resources from `admin/static/`: `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/static/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js`. the strange thing is, I later added the entire `static` folder inside `admin` directory but still it cannot find the above bootstrap.min.js link. Here is my app/**init**.py file where I am registering the blueprints with `app`

```
from .admin import admin as admin_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint, url_prefix='/admin')

from .home import home as home_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)
```

and home/views.py

```
@home.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    """
    Render the dashboard template on the /dashboard route
    """
    return render_template('home/dashboard.html', title="Dashboard")

@home.route('/admin/dashboard')
@login_required
def admin_dashboard():
    prevent non-admins from accessing the page
    if not current_user.is_admin:
         abort(403)

    return render_template('home/admin_dashboard.html', title="Admin Dashboard")
```

the base.html is listed with some static resources to load.

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendors/themify-icons/css/themify-icons.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendors/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendors/selectFX/css/cs-skin-elastic.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

According to the docs, providing the static_url_path to prefixed pages should work, do anyone have a clue on what happening wrong here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks